# Implementing a simple version of readdir with system call

Tags: c, linux, directory, filesystems, system-calls

I am reading the following famous book.

- B. W. Kernighan, and D. M. Ritchie, The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition, Prentice Hall, 1988.

In the last chapter, section 8.6, authors give an example of a program that prints the sizes of *all* files in a directory and its possible sub-directories. The following is a slight modification of the code given in the book. Through this example, the authors try to show an implementation of the well known functions [`opendir`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [`readdir`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), and [`closedir`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html) with the aid of *system calls* [`open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [`close`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html), [`stat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).

The main difference between the following code and the original one in the book is that within the function `read_dir` the authors use

```
while (read(dp->fd, (char *) &dirbuf, sizeof(dirbuf)) == sizeof(dirbuf))
```

which I have replaced with

```
while (ld = read_dirent(dp->fd))
```

with `read_dirent` as *my* replacement for `read`. Indeed, authors used `read` to get a directory entry on each loop iteration and fill `dirbuf` with it. Apparently, this does not work on modern linux kernels due to different file systems and directory entry structures as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144807/why-does-linux-use-getdents-on-directories-instead-of-read). Actually, in old Unix versions, directory entries were 16 bytes, using 2 bytes for the inode and 14 bytes for file names. Using `read` made sense, because the directory entries on the disk were all the same size, which is not the case in modern linux systems. Indeed, in modern linux, each directory entries have different sizes.

To make this work on modern linux, we have to implement a function like `read_dirent` that gets a directory entry on each call and returns a pointer to that entry. For this purpose, I found out that I have to use the [`getdents`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) system call. My current version of `read_dirent` only works for directories with no sub-directory. Here is the question.

> What would be an efficient way to implement `read_dirent` by a lower level system call (not necessarily `getdents` if you are aware of anything else) which is easy and appropriate for *pedagogical* purposes?

---

## Code

Here is the whole code in just one file. I tested this with `gcc` and it compiles without any errors. I tried to separate different sections by comments of the form `/*---*/`. You may get a good insight by tracking the whole process with a debugger like `gdb`.

```
/* This program prints sizes of all files within a directory, recursively. */

void fsize(char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Default is the current directory.
    if (argc == 1)
        fsize(".");
    else
        while (--argc > 0)
            fsize(*++argv);
    
    return 0;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void dirwalk(char *, void (*)(char *));

// Print size of a file.
void fsize(char *name)
{
    struct stat stbuf;

    if (stat(name, &stbuf) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fsize: cannot access %s\n", name);
        return;
    }
    if (S_ISDIR(stbuf.st_mode))
    {
        dirwalk(name, fsize);
        return;
    }
    printf("%8ld %s\n", stbuf.st_size, name);
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define MAXPATH 1024
#define NAMEMAX 256                 // Longest filename component; system-dependent

typedef struct                      // Portable directory entry
{
    long ino;                       // Inode number
    char name[NAMEMAX + 1];         // Name
} DirEnt;

typedef struct                      // Minimal Dir; no buffering, etc
{
    int    fd;                      // File descriptor for directory
    DirEnt d;                       // The directory entry
} Dir;

Dir *open_dir(char *);
DirEnt *read_dir(Dir *);
void close_dir(Dir *);

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include <string.h>

// Apply fcn to all files in dir.
void dirwalk(char *dir, void(*fcn)(char *))
{
    char name[MAXPATH];
    DirEnt *dp;
    Dir *dfd;

    if ((dfd = open_dir(dir)) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "dirwalk: cannot open %s\n", dir);
        return;
    }
    while ((dp = read_dir(dfd)) != NULL)
    {
        // Skip self and parent directories.
        if (strcmp(dp->name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dp->name, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        // Plus 2 accounts for for / and the null terminator.
        if (strlen(dir) + strlen(dp->name) + 2 > sizeof(name))
            fprintf(stderr, "dirwalk: name %s/%s too long\n", dir, dp->name);
        else
        {
            sprintf(name, "%s/%s", dir, dp->name);
            (*fcn)(name);
        }
    }
    close_dir(dfd);
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

// Open a directory for read_dir calls.
Dir *open_dir(char *dirname)
{
    int fd;
    struct stat stbuf;
    Dir *dp;

    if ((fd = open(dirname, O_RDONLY, 0)) == -1 ||
        fstat(fd, &stbuf) == -1 ||
        !S_ISDIR(stbuf.st_mode) ||
        (dp = (Dir *)(malloc(sizeof(Dir)))) == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    dp->fd = fd;

    return dp;
}

// Close directory opened by opendir.
void close_dir(Dir *dp)
{
    if (dp)
    {
        close(dp->fd);
        free(dp);
    }
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

typedef struct linux_dirent         // Local directory entry 
{   
    long           d_ino;           // Inode number
    off_t          d_off;           // Offset to next linux_dirent
    unsigned short d_reclen;        // Length of this linux_dirent
    char           d_name[];        // Name
} LinuxDirEnt;

LinuxDirEnt *read_dirent(int);

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Read directory enteries in sequence.
DirEnt *read_dir(Dir *dp)
{
    // Local directory structure
    LinuxDirEnt *ld;
    // Portable directory structure           
    static DirEnt d;
    
    while (ld = read_dirent(dp->fd))
    {
        // Slot is not in use.
        if (ld->d_ino == 0)
            continue;
        d.ino = ld->d_ino;
        strncpy(d.name, ld->d_name, NAMEMAX);
        // Ensure termination.
        d.name[NAMEMAX] = '\0';
        return &d;
    }
    return NULL;
}

LinuxDirEnt *read_dirent(int fd)
{
    static int nread = 0;
    static int bpos = 0;
    static char buf[BUFSIZE];
    static LinuxDirEnt *d;
    
    if (nread == 0)
    {
        nread = syscall(SYS_getdents, fd, buf, BUFSIZE);
        if (nread == 0)
            return NULL;
        bpos = 0;
    }
    else
        bpos += d->d_reclen;
    d = (LinuxDirEnt *)(buf + bpos);
    nread -= d->d_reclen;

    return d;
}
```

Comment: If those are supposed to be multiple source files, please split them into separate code blocks so we can see where they begin and end.

Comment: It looks like multiple source files because each file begins with a bunch of `#include`

Comment: Why doesn't this work with subdirectories? That's what `if (S_ISDIR(stbuf.st_mode))` handles.

Comment: @Barmar: Try it out. My `read_dirent` function is not good enough for this purpose. It mixes the data taken by `getdents` when there are subdirectories.

Comment: You're supposed to use `opendir()` and `readdir()`, not open the directory directly.

Comment: @Barmar: I know that as I pointed in the question. However, I want to do this for pedagogical purposes. This is not a production code but rather some exercise given to students.

Comment: Could you narrow down the problem? What specifically is it doing wrong when it gets to a subdirectory?

Comment: I think the problem is using a static variable for the return from `read_dir()`. When you go into a subdirectory, that overwrites the static variable.

Comment: Here's an exercise: This code burns up stack space, allocating (and `sprintf()`'ing) a fresh buffer with each recursive call to `dirwalk()`. Revise this to use only one buffer whose suffix is manipulated at each level. It makes the "_prefix_" aspect of "path to here" more apparent and uses less stack space.

Comment: @Barmar: The problem is with buffering. Changing `BUFSIZE` to 32, the code works fine with directories that have sub-directories provided that all directory entries have a size less than 32 bytes. With this buffer size, I somehow force `getdents` to return *only one* directory entry on each call. This prevents from mixing the data by `read_dirent` on different calls. However, this does not seem to be a stable solution as there are directory entries with a size of more than 32 bytes. In old UNIX, all directory entries had a size of 16 bytes, making the authors' code valid for those.

Comment: I found [this similar post](https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/i965wx/stuck_on_implementation_of_readdir_using_getdents/) on reddit, which has not been answered.